# Why the arraylist empties itself when it is called optionPressed method?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Making a simple BrainTrain app, the `updateAnswer` method gives out random answers to the question but the issue comes up whenever i call the `optionsPressed` method and try getting any of the object, the arrayList gives out `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
package com.example.nishantsaini.braintrain;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import static android.R.color.black;
import static android.R.color.holo_blue_bright;
import static android.R.color.holo_blue_dark;
import static android.R.color.holo_blue_light;
import static android.R.color.holo_green_light;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Random rnd = new Random();
boolean gameisActive = false;
int count = 0;
CountDownTimer cd;
int var1,var2;
ArrayList<Button> options;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cd = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            Log.i("Time Left:", Long.toString(l / 1000));
            TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
            timer.setText("0:" + String.format("%02d", (l / 1000)));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);
            LinearLayout onFinishLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.onFinishLayout);
            /*score.setText( "You got " + getScore() + "right!");
            */

        }
    };
    options = new ArrayList<>();
    options.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.option2));
    options.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.option1));
    options.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.option3));
    options.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.option4));
}

public void start(View view) {



    cd.start();

    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    updateQuestion();
    updateAnswers(options);

    start.setText("Replay");

}

public void optionPressed(View view){

    ColorDrawable blue_d = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_b));
    ColorDrawable blue_l = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_l));
    ColorDrawable blue_b = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_b));
    ColorDrawable green = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

    Drawable color = blue_b;
    while(options.size() > 0) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(options.size());
        Button b = options.get(index);

        if (color == blue_b){
            color = blue_d;
            b.setBackground(color);
        }
        else if (color == blue_d){
            color = green;
            b.setBackground(color);

        }
        else if (color == green){
            color = blue_l;
            b.setBackground(color);

        }
        else if (color == blue_l)
        {
            color = blue_b;
            b.setBackground(color);
        }
        options.remove(index);
    }

    updateQuestion();
    updateScore();
    updateAnswers(options);

}

public void updateQuestion(){
    var1 = 5 + (int)(Math.random()*20);
    var2 = 5 + (int)(Math.random()*20);
    TextView question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    question.setText(Integer.toString(var1) +" + " + Integer.toString(var2) + " = ");
    question.setPadding(0,50,0,0);
}

public void updateScore(){

    count++;
    int correct = 0;
    TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.points);
    score.setText(Integer.toString(correct) + "/" + Integer.toString(count));
}

public void updateAnswers(ArrayList<Button> arrayList ){

    Button b;
    int answer = var1 + var2;
    int indexAtWhichRealAnswerGoes = 1+ (int) (Math.random()*3);
    int id ;
    Log.i("arraylist size",Integer.toString(options.size()));

    b = arrayList.get(indexAtWhichRealAnswerGoes);
    b.setText(Integer.toString(answer));
    id = b.getId();
    arrayList.remove(indexAtWhichRealAnswerGoes);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        int randomanswer = (answer-7) + (int)(Math.random()*(answer+7));
        b = arrayList.get(i);
        b.setText(Integer.toString(randomanswer));

    }
    arrayList.add((Button) findViewById(id));
    Log.i("arraylist size",Integer.toString(arrayList.size()));

}
}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace, but I bet this come from `int indexAtWhichRealAnswerGoes = 1+ (int) (Math.random()*3);
... arrayList.get(indexAtWhichRealAnswerGoes);` on a list that as been emptied in the `while(options.size() > 0){.. options.remove(randomIndex);}` Check the logic there. But you are clearly removing every options from that list.

Comment: From where you call `optionPressed` this method?

Comment: The detail message and stack trace accompanying the exception are the very first things to look at, even before the code.  If you want our help then provide at least those.  Generally, however, we want to see a [mcve].  That can be a bit tricky to produce from a GUI app, but on the plus side, the process of constructing one has a decent chance of helping you discover the error for yourself.

Comment: Thank you @AxelH, added the options back at the end of the while of that while loop, worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you call `updateAnswers(options);` using the list that you previously emptied

```
while(options.size() > 0) {
    int index = rnd.nextInt(options.size());
    ...
    options.remove(index);
}
...
updateAnswers(options);
```

At that point, the list is empty.

In the method, you safely used `for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {`  to prevent any error **but before that** we see

```
int indexAtWhichRealAnswerGoes = 1+ (int) (Math.random()*3);
...
b = arrayList.get(indexAtWhichRealAnswerGoes);
```

You get that random index without checking the size of the list. (`List` that is empty at that point).

---

If you want to keep the list with its value, but the logic can't be change so the `remove` is necessary, you need to do a copy of the list to work on that one, and pass the original to the method `updateAnswers`.

```
List<Button> copyOptions = new ArrayList<>(options);
```

It will share the same instance, but you can update the list `copyOptions` without having any impact on `options`